# How to view entire commit when log is filtered by file in tig

Tags: git

If [tig](http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/) is invoked with `tig log some/file.txt` the log will show all commits affecting that file. Pressing Enter on a line like `commit d5dd1d658e5d79701fb9d028479a0fcb26a033fa` will open the diff view showing the changes to `some/file.txt` in that commit but only the changes to that file:

[image: Screenshot of tig log view with diff]

I would like to be able to view the entire contents of the commit, unfiltered by the filename. I.e. switch to a view that's the same as that generated if you run `tig show d5dd1d658e5d79701fb9d028479a0fcb26a033fa`:

[image: Screen shot of tig diff view]

I've tried all the views and read the manual but haven't found a way. Is it possible?

Comment: Perhaps post a feature request to the [issue tracker](https://github.com/jonas/tig/issues)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>%</kbd> toggles the file filter in any view and does what you're asking for. You can even switch back and forth between the file's history and the repository's history, or the file-constrained view of a commit and the commit in its entirety.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Totally missed this in the manual, "% — Toggle file filtering in order to see the full diff instead of only the diff concerning the currently selected file."